# I don't know why viewForHeaderInSection is not called in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I don't know why `viewForHeaderInSection` is not called in swift3. I've added `heightForHeaderInSection` in UITableView but not called unfortunately. Please help me to check how to fixed it.

[image]

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return homeStrs.count
    case 1:
        return accountStrs.count
    case 2:
        return otherStrs.count
    default:
        return otherStrs.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = menuTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero;
    cell.lbNoti.isHidden = true
    switch ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section) {
    case 0:
        cell.lbMenuTitle?.text = homeStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage (named: homeImgStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    case 1:
        cell.lbMenuTitle?.text = accountStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage (named: accountImgStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    case 2:
        cell.lbMenuTitle?.text = otherStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage (named: otherImgStrs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    default:
        cell.lbMenuTitle?.text = "Other"
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch (section) {
    case 1:
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        let menuHeaderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.frame.size.width, height: 28))
        menuHeaderLabel.text = "Account Settings"
        headerView.addSubview(menuHeaderLabel)
        return headerView
    case 2:
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        let menuHeaderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.frame.size.width, height: 28))
        menuHeaderLabel.text = "Others"
        headerView.addSubview(menuHeaderLabel)
        return headerView
    default:
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.frame.size.width, height: 0))
        return headerView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You sure you've added UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource in your ViewController Class

Comment: That's custom tableview and I've attached delegate & datasource method in storyboard. Btw, I've edit my answer as showing attached delegate & datasource in storyboard.

Comment: "That's custom tableview and I've attached delegate & datasource method in storyboard" That's not good enough. Your view controller must _explicitly adopt_ UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource or your methods will not be called.

Comment: @matt that's great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Was holding off on implementing UITableViewDelegate so I figured that couldn't be the issue. Once I added the delegate, everything worked.

Answer (score 17):

If someone else is having the same issue... Adding this line in viewDidLoad called the delegate methods therefore made the header appear:

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 80
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, adding `self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 80.0` to viewDidLoad did the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue occured with me that's because **tableview** find difficulties in calculating **height** for header but as I was using **automatic height calculation** from **xCode 9**, I cannot give any explicit height value as mentioned above. After some experimentation I **got solution**, we have to override this method as,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return 44.0f;
}
```

Although I have **checked** both options

1. **Automatic Height Calculation**
2. **Automatic Estimated Height Calculation**

from **storyboard** as apple says, but still I got this weird error.

**Please Note**: This Error was shown only on **IOS-10** version not on **IOS-11** version. Maybe it's a bug from xCode. Thanks